# How i can use jQuery and Spry framework both in a web-application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to use jQuery and Spry both in my web-application. how it's possible.

the two thing i used from different different framework :>

tab from spry and famespam from jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery independently of anything else, doesn't matter what other libraries you choose. All you need to be careful about is the `$` variable, which might be used somewhere else.

That's why jQuery has the `noConflict()` method. If your other framework uses the `$` variable, simply do

```
$.noConflict();
// other libraries can use the $ now ...
// jQuery is still available under the jQuery variable, eg.
jQuery("foo").click(...)
```

[More information about `$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)